# Angular Stop select/mdselect from resetting to placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-material

[image]
So i have this filter form and i am using angular material for my design.I get a predicted error every time i plugin a set of wrong integers and do a search. The problem is, what ever data user typed should remain,other wise user would have to re type/select everything and try again. its working on every other selectors and inputs but not filterable properties, it's keep resetting back to its placeholder even thou the form throw an error and stayed open

here is the pic of what i am talking about. the red underlined selectors resettled to its placeholders  [image]

**here is html for bugged selector code**

```
 <md-select aria-label="Multi Value Filter {{$index}}" class="md-accent" flex="25" flex-sm="50" ng-repeat="selectFilter in $ctrl.selectFilters" placeholder="{{selectFilter.name}}" ng-model="selectFilter.selectedVal">
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in selectFilter.selectValues" value="{{option}}">{{option.value}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
```

Comment: Hi, Please check it with removing the ng-change function, if it cleared the issue. Then please make changes in the function.

Comment: hey, the selector i have problems with doesn't have a ng-change